# g++ [[noreturn]] on a virtual method

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I've run into some trouble trying to clean up g++ compiler warnings.

Say I have this class:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    [[noreturn]] virtual void will_throw() { throw 0; }
};
```

And inside a non-void function I invoke `will_throw` without returning.

If I do this by value, i.e.:

```cpp
int g()
{
    A a;
    a.will_throw();
}
```

then I get no `-Wreturn-type` warnings.

If I do it by pointer:

```cpp
int g()
{
    A a;
    A* aptr = &a;
    aptr->will_throw();
}
```

Then I get "warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]"

If I remove `virtual` from the declaration of `A::will_throw` then calling it on a pointer also produces no warnings. Calling the method on a reference seems to produce a warning if the method is pure-virtual, but not otherwise.

I wasn't able to find anything saying this is how it's supposed to work, and none of these cases produce warnings in Clang. Is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: certainly seems like a bug to me. I was able to repro this with GCC 9, and Clang 9 does not seem to have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is virtual, the compiler doesn’t know (without tracking assignments) that the call through a pointer (or reference) is to `A::will_throw` and not to some overriding function that might not be `noreturn`.  Since it’s just a warning, both behaviors (or never warning, or always warning!) are conforming.

Comment: This seems counterintuitive to me. The virtual function itself has the attribute `noreturn` and I should think that as far as the compiler is concerned that is a sufficient promise that the override will not return. I understand there is some ambiguity as to what attributes mean to inheritance, but I don't know any other way to specify this intent. If GCC's current behavior is not strictly incorrect I would still maintain that it could be improved.

Comment: @squeevee: Given that it’s undefined behavior for a `[[noreturn]]` function to actually return, propagating it to overriders seems fairly drastic (along with having strictly less expressive power: maybe you mean the base implementation to never be used and to report misuse as an exception).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by this. The problem isn't the behavior (or the expensiveness) of the executable, nor in actual practice is there need to enforce this intent with error checks at runtime. That all works fine as-is. But the compiler's warnings indicate that it has misinterpreted what I regard to be fairly clear intent.

Comment: @squeevee: My point is that the standard doesn’t say that `[[nodiscard]]` is inherited (with plausible reason), and that seems a good reason for GCC to treat it that way even for advisory diagnostics.